# How to insert concatenated auto incrementing primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add reservation id to a table in mysql. I should add it as R001,R0002 etc.
The number part should be auto incremented.
I want to do this when inserting data not at selecting data.
Is there any way to do this?
I refered to many posts on stackover flow but there didn't work.

Comment: Just use an incrementing integer key.  It is much easier the manager and simpler for foreign key references.

Comment: Is it R##n or R###n?  your question is not clear.  What benefit is there to doing this padding vs just 1, 2, 3, etc?  For display is one thing, but for storing you want it to be just a plain integer.  Makes joining and indexing much easier/more efficient.  If you're padding it stored, what happens when you run out of numbers? Does R001 need to be updated to R0001?  Integers - abide by KISS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native, built-in support (in MySQL) for the functionality you describe.

Is there a way to do it?

Yes, this this can be achieved. But it's non-trivial. One approach is to use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, and to emulate an Oracle `SEQUENCE` object. And most of the attempts I've seen at doing that are flawed, and don't actually work. But it is possible.

But the exercise of demonstrating that is largely academic, because implementing that kind of functionality in MySQL isn't practical.

If you want AUTO_INCREMENT, just use a simple integer. And have your SQL work with a simple integer column.

When the value of that column is retrieved, it can be formatted for display, however you want. But put that functionality closer to the UI, not in the database.

My two cents.